# jQuery loading empty image first in slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, everyone, I am a total noob at jQuery, but I'm learning, and I've tried to research and implement a very simple slideshow. Looks thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs = [
    '../Images/Slideshow/01.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/02.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/03.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/04.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/05.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/06.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/07.jpg'];
    var cnt = imgs.length;

    $(function () {
        setInterval(Slider, 3000);
    });



    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn(2000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

And I have this in the body down yonder:

```
<img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" height="450" width="450" border="0" />
```

It runs alright for its purposes, but it's kind of irksome that it starts out with a big empty blank square image box for several seconds before proceeding with the slide show. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: you can bind onload event to specific image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img id="imageSlide" alt="" src='../Images/Slideshow/01.jpg' height="450" width="450" border="0" />
```

Now put the source of first image as the last one in array as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs = [
    '../Images/Slideshow/02.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/03.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/04.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/05.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/06.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/07.jpg',
    '../Images/Slideshow/01.jpg'];
    var cnt = imgs.length;

    $(function () {
        setInterval(Slider, 3000);
    });



    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn(2000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your src in the image tag is blank when the page loads, so you need to fill it with an image like so:

```
    $('#imageSlide').prop('src','../Images/Slideshow/01.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Call Slider(); immediately before setInterval();